# make changes to nodes between other sibling nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes, siblings

I am a beginner to xslt and would very much appreciate your help for the below-mentioned issue.
Inside node `<case>`, I want to select `<s>` nodes between its first `<beginning>` and first `<end>` sibling nodes , the second `<beginning>` and the second `<end>` and respectively the n<sup>th</sup> beginning and the n<sup>th</sup> node; and add the attribute `@attribute:unsolved` to them. Meanwhile, I want to keep the rest of the xml file intact.
My input and desired output are shown below. Thanks a lot for your help.

XML INPUT:

```
<content>
    <issue>1</issue>
    <status>to be solved</status>
</content> 
<case>
    <beginning>problem</beginning>
    <s>this</s>
    <s>is</s>
    <s>a</s>
    <s>problem</s>
    <end>problem</end>
    <s>no</s>
    <s>problem</s>
    <s>here</s>
    <s>.</s>
    <beginning>problem</beginning>
    <s>problem</s>
    <s>again</s>
    <end>problem</end>
    <s>no</s>
    <s>issue</s>
</case>
```

Desired output:

```
<content>
    <issue>1</issue>
    <status>to be solved</status>
</content>
<case>
    <beginning>problem</beginning>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>this</s>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>is</s>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>a</s>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>problem</s>
    <end>problem</end>
    <s>no</s>
    <s>problem</s>
    <s>here</s>
    <s>.</s>
    <beginning>problem</beginning>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>problem</s>
    <s attribute='unsolved'>again</s>
    <end>problem</end>
    <s>no</s>
    <s>issue</s>
</case>
```

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried. What programming language are you using to achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to write an XSLT stylesheet for this transformation from one XML file to another XML file.

Comment: Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 look at any example using `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="beginning"`, the spec has https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples.

Comment: Does all `<s>` tags have the attribute as 'unsolved'?

Comment: no! I just want to add the attribute unsolved to the nodes which are between <beginning> and <end> nodes. The rest of <s> nodes remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, then your XPath will be show like:

```
`//beginning/following::s[./following::end]
[
count(.|//end/following::s[./following::beginning])
!=
count(//end/following::s[./following::beginning])
]`
```

[image: Please see this is picture]